# Jackson deserialize response of restfullyii

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I actually have some web-services make with restfullyii in PHP.

But I have some troubles to deserialize response of my web-services with jackson.

This is an example of response :

```
{"success":true,"message":"Record(s) Found","data":{"totalCount":"1","user":{...}}}
```

To deserialize this response I make this model :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class response {

@JsonProperty("data")
private HashMap<String, Object> data;

@JsonProperty("message")
private String message;

@JsonProperty("success")
private Boolean success;

public HashMap<String, Object> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(HashMap<String, Object> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

}
```

And to deserialize user I use these lines :
(rst is a result of deserialize response)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {

                String rstTxt = String.valueOf(rst.getData().get("user"));
                System.out.println(rstTxt);
                user user = mapper.readValue(rstTxt, user.class);
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But it doesn't work because "rst.getData().get("user")" returns a string in this schema :
{ attribute = value }
Indeed, the following exception is returned :

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

Have you an idea about how I could do to deserialize user attribute ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite guessing but maybe, since you've defined a `Map<String, Object>`, your User should be already deserialized into an Object, and maybe you should just try to cast it:

```
User user = (User) rst.getData().get("user");
```

otherwise you can modify slightly your code to match exactly the response, like:

```
public class Response {
    private String message;
    private Boolean success;
    private Data data;
}
```

and

```
public class Data {
    private String totalCount;
    private User user;
}
```

In this way you should get everything immeadiately deserialized.

Tip: if your variable names are the same you don't need the @JsonProperty annotation!